# I'm looking for a batch file to delete jpg's from a .txt file list

Tags: list, batch-file, jpeg

I'm looking for a batch file to delete jpg's from a .txt file list

E:\test\1 has 7 images 1.jpg to 7.jpg
list.txt has list of files to be deleted 1.jpg, 2.jpg

Thanks for your help

I found code that will copy the .jpgs in my list.txt to another folder.
Instead of copying I need it to delete,

```
@echo off
set src_folder=E:\test\1
set dst_folder=E:\test\2
set file_list=E:\test\list.txt

if not exist "%dst_folder%" mkdir "%dst_folder%"

for /f "delims=" %%f in (%file_list%) do (
xcopy "%src_folder%\%%f" "%dst_folder%\"
)
```

I found this solution using excel
column A del
column B list of images
column C Concatenate(A1,B1) and copy and paste column C in a batch file run in same directory as images.

Comment: This site isn't a code writing service btw

Comment: You could post the code that you have tried so far, and we could improve on it then.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```bat
@Echo Off
(Set file_list=E:\test\list.txt)
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("%file_list%") Do If Exist "%%~A" Del "%%~A"
```

You could even drag and drop your list.txt onto this single line batch script.

```bat
@For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("%~1") Do @(If Exist "%%~A" Del "%%~A")
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the parentheses around the `set` command line? let me recommend to use the syntax `set "file_list=E:\test\list.txt"` instead...

Comment: What is the purpose of the double quotes around your example?

Comment: Parenthesis in the `set "name=value"` are usualy used to avoid append unwanted spaces and to prevent interpret special characters.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a single line batch file:

```
@for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("E:\test\list.txt") do @del "%%~I" 2>nul
```

The command **FOR** processes each line from the specified text file and executes command **DEL** with the line read from the file.

No file existence check is made before deleting the file. Instead the file is deleted with error message suppressed by redirecting it from handle **STDERR** to the device **NUL**.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `for /?`

Read also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).